# Get gerrit patchsets via topic (for multiple repositories)

Tags: git, patch, gerrit

We have a couple of submodules in our project. So let's say one developer implements a new feature that affects several of those submodules and uploades his changes to gerrit patchsets with all the same topic.

So when I want to download his changes I can get the download links from the gerrit webinterface. But I would have to do this for every submodule.

Is there an easy way to automagically fetch the patch sets via the topic name?
Something like `git fetch origin refs/changes/*topicname*` ?

Or will I have to use gerrit REST API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote a little script for this - it was easier than I thought.
Here is what to do:

- get the desired patch sets via gerrit query, like this:
  `ssh -p 29418 myserver gerrit query --patch-sets topic:mytopic AND project:myproject`
- As gerrit will output a lot of data per patch set, we have to 'grep' and 'sed' it's output a little bit:
  `grep ref: | sed s%\ \ \ \ ref:\ %%`
  so we get a nice list of the refs to fetch
- we can use this output with xargs  `xargs -r -n 1 get_n_tag_patchset.sh`
- where my `get_n_tag_patchset.sh` looks like this:
  `git fetch --recurse-submodules=no origin $1`
  `git tag -f $1 FETCH_HEAD`

I merged the first three points together in one command line:
`ssh -p 29418 myserver gerrit query --patch-sets topic:mytopic AND project:myproject | grep ref: | sed s%\ \ \ \ ref:\ %% | xargs -r -n 1 get_n_tag_patchset.sh`

So I end up with all the patch sets of the desired topic in my local repo, each with a tag on it.
Doing this for all of my submodules (where 'myproject' has to be replaced to match the submodule, of course) will do the rest. :-)

Comment: Just in case anyone wonders: the tags can easily be removed by:`git tag -l refs/changes/* | xargs -n 1 git tag -d`

Comment: Additional "meta" refs show up since Gerrit 3.x. They can be removed with:
`git show-ref --abbrev | grep meta | sed s%.*refs%refs% | xargs -P 5 -r -n 1 git update-ref -d`

Answer (score 1):

The [latest GitMinutes episode](http://episodes.gitminutes.com/2014/07/gitminutes-30-luca-milanesio-on-gerrit.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A%20gitminutes-all%20%28GitMinutes%20-%20All%20Posts%29) (July 2014) mentions that, and  Luca Milanesio, a seasoned Gerrit contributor, details it in [its blog post](http://gitenterprise.me/2014/07/07/gitminutes-30-luca-milanesio-on-gerrit-code-review/):

> With the forthcoming support of multi-repositories atomic commits in Gerrit, it will be possible to merge multiple changes on multiple repositories at the same time for a single topic.
>   This feature is not ready yet but coming hopefully in the near future and Google Gerrit Team developers and contributors are working on it.

This is not there yet [in Gerrit 2.9](https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.9/dev-plugins.html) though.

Comment: Thank you, this is great news to here. This seems to become a cool feature. Hopefully we will manage to get around this until it is available...

Comment: Has anyone heard of any progress regarding this feature? Actually I can't find anything about it except the GitMinutes mentioned above.

Comment: Gerrit V2.12 has a "Submit Whole Topic" feature that sounds promising. Looking forward to test it (as soon as I find the time to)...

Comment: @Roman seems you can submit and cherry-pick the whole topic,but no way to download the whole topic.